# Tutorial for JAX-RPC webservice development

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rpc

I am looking for a tutorial on JAX-RPC webservice development and my platform is weblogic 10.3

Regards,
imran

Comment: this is not a real question, we will not do your work

Comment: Hi Luiggi i havent said to develop a project for me i ask about link to tutorial. Because Oracle Eclipse (OEPE) dont support JAX-RPC development.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below link if anyone want to develop JAX-RPC webservice for Weblogic

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webserv_rpc/index.html

Regards,
imran